# Informing screen readers when new content is loaded via ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, accessibility

I'm loading some additional content on a page when a user selects a button. The new content will be very clear visually, but are there any steps necessary to make sure the new content is available / obvious to screen readers?

I found two best practices that seem to indicate more steps are necessary: [Inform assistive technologies of changes in content](https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?best_practice_id=968) &  [Ensure assistive technologies are aware of content changes in real time](https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?best_practice_id=1949):

> Developers must use certain methods to alert assistive technologies that content has changed through JavaScript. When these methods are not used, users of assistive technology such as screen readers may have an outdated/stale view of page content.

I haven't been able to find specific javascript or markup that should be used to make the change clear.

There are a couple different kinds of content we might load:

- Search results in response to a query (eg typeahead search)
- Longer descriptions (eg loading a couple paragraphs of details for a record after selecting a search result)

Comment: The short answer is yes, you absolutely need to provide some additional markup using the [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/) specification from the W3C.  The long answer depends entirely on what kind of new content you are loading and how the user interacts with it.  Please refine the question with more detail and I can try to help further.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRepsher -- I've added a few more details above. If that's not enough to go on, please let me know specifically what would be helpful to know.

Comment: Sounds like you're still in the preliminary design phase, so I can point you to resources for those types of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general content types you specified:

> Longer descriptions (e.g. loading a couple paragraphs of details for a record after selecting a search result)

It sounds like you just want an accordion (show/hide) functionality.  Take a look at [section 2.2 of *WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1*](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion) for a detailed discussion.  It ends with a [simple accordion example with code](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/accordion/accordion1.html).

> Search results in response to a query (e.g. typeahead search)

I see this described in various terms, but most commonly as an auto-complete widget (search the web for those keywords).  Here's a nice [example of a very accessible one](https://haltersweb.github.io/Accessibility/autocomplete.html) which describes the features and behavior to target for proper keyboard control and screen reading.

Also, If you are providing an auto-completion feature, directly where the user is typing, then make sure it's marked up properly using the [`aria-autocomplete` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-autocomplete) and the completed text is always selected.

Lastly, consider providing a mechanism to turn off this functionality.  Some screen reader and low vision users are simply going to find it very distracting (e.g. Google Instant can be turned off in a user's account settings).

Comment: Thank you! One clarification: for "loading details", the details will be populated after an ajax request -- the content is not yet in the DOM when the button is activated. Is there an event that should be fired or specific markup that should be used to indicate that relevant new content has been added to the DOM?

Comment: No, the accordion markup is sufficient.  Essentially, you're asking whether the container element for the AJAX content needs an [`aria-live` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live) set higher than `"off"`, which means that the screen reader may start reading it after the button is pressed.  This is not necessary because the user is given notice already that the button will expand more content inside the element given by `aria-controls`.  The content just needs to exist when it gets focus.